# Add and remove class issue JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove a class that has been added by a previous JQuery event, but it just won't play ball. Please guide me!

This is what applies the class:

```
$('.project').click(function() {
        var imageTotal = $(this).find('.gallery img').length;
        if (imageTotal === 1) {
            $('.next-image', this).hide();
            $('.prev-image', this).hide();
        } else {
            $('.next-image', this).show();
            $('.prev-image', this).show();
        }
        $('img.feature').hide();
        $('.gallery img:nth-of-type(' + imageCounter + ')', this).addClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

And this is what I am trying to remove it with:

```
$('.back').click(function() {
        $('.gallery').hide();
        $('.back').hide();
        $('img.feature').show();
        $(this).parent('.project').find('div').removeClass('active');
        $('.prev-page').show();
    });
```

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="project">
                <img class="feature" src="content/dream1.jpg"/>
                <div class="description">
                    <h3>Exhibition Roadshow</h3>
                    <h4>The Royal Borough of Kensington and Chelsea 2012</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="gallery">
                    <img src="content/dream2.jpg"/>
                    <img src="content/dream3.jpg"/>
                    <img src="content/dream4.jpg"/>
                    <img src="content/dream5.jpg"/>
                    <div class="next-image">&rarr;</div>
                    <div class="prev-image">&larr;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">S</div>
            </div>
```

You can see the live example [here](http://yaocho-digital.com/ella/), if that helps...

Comment: where is `imageCounter` defined?

Comment: @hexblot - please have a look at the live link. Will probs be easier than me explaining by copying and pasting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first issue was:
$(this).parent('.project').**find('div')**.removeClass('active');

but the real issue is, the class DOES get removed, but you fail to terminate the catch event, so it bubbles down to your `.project` on click event that sets the same class again. It all happens at the same time so it seems like the class is never removed.

the solution? add `return false;` at the end of the click event

Comment: btw: i would not have seen the bottom bar if I had not known there had to be more content there.

Comment: Just tried that. Doesn't seem to work either. Really confused as I use the same method to remove the same method works to remove the 'current' class using: '$('img').removeClass('current');'...

Comment: its funny how 2 other people had the same answer after me but theirs gets the upvote :P just another bug: if i select text then drag down, i break the paging and even refreshing the page will not fix it

Comment: Not sure what you mean about selecting text bug. I can't recreate that one. Sorry about the voting up thing, it wasn't me, and their response doesn't fix the issue anyhow! :)

Comment: :P im on chrome, if I press the mouse button down and drag it (as in selecting text), the page scrolls down

Comment: and about the bug: the class DOES get removed, but it gets readded later on

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Could you please explain why 'return false;' is the correct way to do this? I don't quite understand why that works.

Comment: its correct in your case. you use "return false" to prevent the "click" event from bubbling down. when you click somewhere, the click goes down all elements until something stops it

Answer (score 1):

You're removing the class from the wrong element.
This line:

```
$(this).parent('.project').find('div').removeClass('active');
```

Should be like this:

```
$(this).closest('.project').removeClass('active');
```

Since the .project is the element you want to remove the active class. What you're doing above is searching "div" inside the .project element.

Answer (score 0):

In `$('.project').click(function() {` method  `$(this).addClass('active');` adds the active to `$('.project')`...

and you are trying to remove it from childs of `$('.project')`...
what you need is

```
$('.back').click(function() {
        $('.gallery').hide();
        $('.back').hide();
        $('img.feature').show();
        $(this).parent('.project').removeClass('active');
        $('.prev-page').show();
    });
```

Comment: I have added this to the live version, and I am still getting the same problem, please have a look here: http://yaocho-digital.com/ella/